# Setting an icon As tab Indicator in tablayout

Tags: java, android

I am stuck with a tab layout design, I need a tab indicator as shown below in the screenshot. I am having a drawable for that but I am not sure how to make this view.
Please check the favorites bar tab.I need the tab indicator in this way.

[image]

Comment: Make sure your image size is same as All tab image size.

Comment: its not about the size of image I just need the tab indicator as i mentioned. can you help me on this.?

Comment: Please post some code which you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

you have to make a function for this inside your pagerAdapter class.

```
    public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    int[] selectors = {R.drawable.one, R.drawable.two};

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }


    public void setCustomIconsFortabs(){
        for (int i=0; i< getCount(); i++){
            tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setIcon(selectors[i]);
        }
    }
```